# Averaging time series of different lengths

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a number of lists (time series)

```
dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}
```

that I would like to average on another:

```
merged = {'m': [2.33,2.33,3.66,4.0,4.0]}
```

Is there a smart way to find this?

What if the lists have different lengths and I want either an average from what's available, or to pretend all lists happened in the same time frame despite having different numbers of data points?

Comment: In the case they are different lengths, what do you assume about the distribution of the data points in time? Does "happened in the same time frame" assume that the first and last data points happened at the same time in all time series, and the rest are evenly distributed? The proper solution will depend on these assumptions.

Comment: Indeed, I assume that the first and last data points happened at the same time in all time series, and the rest are evenly distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that you tagged this with numpy and scipy, I'm assuming it's OK to use scientific python functions. A terse way to accomplish the first task is then

```
$ ipython --pylab
>>> dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}
>>> map(mean, np.array(dictionary.values()).transpose())
[2.3333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 4.0, 4.0]
```

You can of course put this into a dictionary with key 'm' and round off the results to get the result in the form you specified.

As for handling missing values or arrays of different lengths, 
you'd first need to decide how the missing data should be treated.
The way you've asked the second question feels too vague.

Comment: shorten to `np.asarray(dictionary.values()).mean(0)`, for python 3 needs list or from_iter.

Comment: Thank you, i was looking for something like this. Concerning the different lengths, as mentioned in the reply above I want to end up with an array of a length equal to the length of the largest list. Endpoints should always map on each other and arrays of different lengths should be assumed to be a continuous signal with different resolution. Does that make sense? I am sure there are mathematical tools for this but I have no idea what they are called.

Answer (score 0):

A simple method for nice data is just

```
from statistics import mean

dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}
merged = {'m': [mean(values) for values in zip(*dictionary.values())]}

merged
#>>> {'m': [2.3333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 4.0, 4.0]}
```

For older Python 3 versions, replace `statistics.mean` with `sum(values) / len(values)`. For Python 2 you'll need to `from __future__ import division` or use `float(len(values)`.

If you want linear interpolation, that's pretty easy too:

```
from statistics import mean
import numpy

dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}

def interpolate_many(lists):
    maxlen = max(map(len, lists))
    interpolation_target = numpy.linspace(0, 1, maxlen)

    for lst in lists:
        x_values = numpy.linspace(0, 1, len(lst))
        yield numpy.interp(interpolation_target, x_values, lst)

interpolated = interpolate_many(dictionary.values())

merged = {'m': [mean(values) for values in zip(*interpolated)]}
merged
#>>> {'m': [2.3333333333333335, 2.5833333333333335, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0]}
```

All this does is pre-process the lists so that the short ones are stretched to the maximum length (`maxlen`, which can be changed if you wish). Then it runs the prior code.

Answer (score 0):

The following code averages the arrays according to the number of elements it found.

```
dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}

mergerd = {'m': []}

i = 0
count = 0
num = len(dictionary)

while True:
    mergerd['m'].append(0)
    for key in dictionary: #for each entry in the dictionary
        if (len(dictionary[key]) <= i): #if the list for that entry doesn't have a element
            continue
        mergerd['m'][i] += dictionary[key][i]
        count += 1
    if count == 0: #if there were no more elements
        mergerd['m'].pop()
        break
    mergerd['m'][i] = mergerd['m'][i]/count
    count = 0
    i += 1

print(mergerd['m'])
```

produces the following output

```
[2.3333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 4.0, 4.0]

if dictionary was equal to {'a': [1,2,3,4,5,3], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1,1,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}
# then the following would be output
[2.3333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 4.0, 4.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

The last two elements of the merged array are 2.0 and 1.0

2 is worked out because there are only two arrays that have a 6th element, their values are 3 and 1, so (3+1)/2 = 2

1 is worked out because there is only one array that has a 7th element, the value is 1 , so 1/1 = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use a basic list comprehension:

```
import numpy
dictionary = {'a': [1,2,3,4,5], 'b': [5,2,3,4,1], 'c': [1,3,5,4,6]}
vals = [dictionary.values()[i][j] for j in range(5) for i in range(3)]
vals = [vals[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(vals), 3)]
merged = {}
merged['m'] = [numpy.mean(item) for item in vals)]
print merged #{'m': [2.3333333333333335, 2.3333333333333335, 3.6666666666666665, 4.0, 4.0]}
```